# Fancy scroll-bar (any directive based) is not working inside ng-view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, perfect-scrollbar

I want to apply a fancy scroll bar on a paragraph which is inside the ng-view.
My module code is

```
var myweb = angular.module('myweb' , ['ngRoute', 'perfect_scrollbar']);
myweb.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider
    .when('/profile', {
      templateUrl : 'ngHtml/profile.html',
      controller  : 'mainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/careers', {
      templateUrl : 'ngHtml/careers.html',
      controller  : 'careersCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo:'/profile'});

});
```

And ngHtml/careers.html is

```
<div class="panel"> 
  <div class="panel-heading bg-primary">
    <h2>{{data.heading}}</h2>
  </div>
  <perfect-scrollbar class="scroller panel-body" wheel-propagation="true" wheel-speed="10" min-scrollbar-length="20">
     ....
     ...
     ..
     .
  </perfect-scrollbar>
</div>
```

This is the [prefect-scrollbar](https://github.com/itsdrewmiller/angular-perfect-scrollbar) i have also tried [ng-scrollbar](https://github.com/asafdav/ng-scrollbar) and others but its not working. I am unable to initiate the function of scrollbar directive inside ng-view.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best group of scroll-bar ( it's free and opine scores ) :

1- [Examples of Group](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/scrollbar_themes_demo.html)
.

2- [Download For Free](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)
.

3- [Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=niEG065e8Aw)
.

Thanks